# Creating routes in a DRY way in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, url-routing

I've been using Symfony for a long time but I'm new to Symfony2. After using the CRUD generator to generate scaffolding for a module called `MediaArea`, I edited my routing to include this rule:

```
_welcome:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: VNNPressboxBundle:MediaArea:new }
```

When I visited that page in the browser, I got this error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Route "mediaarea_create" does not exist.")

When I create the route, naturally, the error goes away. Here's the route:

```
mediaarea_create:
    pattern:  /foo
    defaults: { _controller: VNNPressboxBundle:MediaArea:create }
```

So I could manually create all the routes I need to - `mediaarea_create`, `mediaarea_index`, etc. - but that would be dumb. Is there a way to tell Symfony that I have all these `mediaarea` routes that I need to work?

Comment: Are you trying to attach the routes generated by the CRUD generator (and placed into your bundle) to the main app routing.yml file? Or are you trying to get Symfony to assume the crud routes automatically?

Comment: To answer your first question, I can't find any evidence that the CRUD generator generated any routes at all. If it did, I don't care where they area as long as they work. For your second question, it would be nice if it did that, but my main pursuit is to find the "right" way to handle the routing in this case.

Comment: I would check in your src/{namespaceName}/{bundleName}/Resources/config folder for any generated routes. If nothing is there you will probably need to create the routes manually. There is a way to have symfony automatically create them. I'm not 100% sure how to do this without using the FOSRestBundle: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Routing/Loader/RestRouteLoader.php, but you could have a look at their bundle to see how they did it.

Comment: I did find `src/VNN/PressboxBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml` but there were no generated routes within it. I'll check out FOSRestBundle. Thanks.

Comment: why would designing urls be dumb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: ok, may not answer the question, it's just a long comment...

Why not using an `abstract` **base controller** with annotations instead?

```
abstract class AbstractCrudController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/show/{slug}")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template
     */
    public function showAction($slug) { /* Do stuff */ }
}

class MediaController extends AbstractCrudController { }
class UserController  extends AbstractCrudController { }
```

If your subclasses need a **different behavior** you can always override `showAction()` or **add any action** you want. Then you just need to import `MediaController` and `UserController` in your `routing.yml` (just one import for each controller):

```
somename1:
    resource: "@AcmeHelloBundle/Controller/MediaController.php"
    type: annotation
    prefix: /media

somename2:
    resource: "@AcmeHelloBundle/Controller/UserController.php"
    type: annotation
    prefix: /user
```

Your routes then becomes automatically `acme_hello_media_show` and `acme_hello_user_show`. Debug with:

```
php app/console router:debug
```